# How can I do a replace with values from a table

Tags: sql, loops, replace, with-statement

This is my current code, what I want to do is rather than hard code this replace is put those values in a table and use those values to do the replace without a while or cursor.  Keep in mind multiple replaces may happen to the same field for instance Mr. Guy would replace the "." but then would also need to replace "Mr ".

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(di.FirstName), '.', ''), ',', ''), 'Mr ', ''), 'Dr ', ''), 'Mrs ', ''), 'Ms', '')
FROM core..asdf di
```

Comment: Do you need to run that in a DBMS other than MS SQL Server? That one does not contain the REGEXP_REPLACE() function, while a plethora of other DBMSs does.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports both GROUP_CONCAT() (or equivalent, like LISTAGG() in Vertica),
You can

- create an in-line table with the titles you want to remove,
- group-concatenate that in-line table into a single string, bar separated
- surround that bar-separated list by rounded parentheses, and add '\b' for "word" boundary, '\.?' meaning zero or one times the dot character (and not any character), and '\s*' for one or more white spaces
- and finally use that regular expression you just created on a REGEXP_REPLACE() call.

```
WITH
indata(fname) AS (
              SELECT 'Mr Arthur'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Mrs Tricia'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Ms Eccentrica'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Dr Gag'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Mr. Arthur'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Mrs. Tricia'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Ms. Eccentrica'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Dr. Gag'
)
,
titles(title) AS (
              SELECT 'Mr'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Mrs'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Ms'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Dr'
)
,
regx(regx) AS (
  SELECT
    '('||LISTAGG(title USING PARAMETERS separator='|')||')\b\.?\s*'
  -- OR GROUP_CONCAT(title,',') in other DBMSs ...
  FROM titles
)
-- control query ...
-- SELECT * FROM regx;
-- out          regx         
-- out ----------------------
-- out  (Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr)\.?\s*
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(fname,regx) AS fname
FROM indata CROSS JOIN regx;
-- out    fname    
-- out ------------
-- out  Arthur
-- out  Tricia
-- out  Eccentrica
-- out  Gag
-- out  Arthur
-- out  Tricia
-- out  Eccentrica
-- out  Gag
```